# How do I remove the "from iPhone" dock icon popping up, MacOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, dock

I updated my OS to High Sierra, 10.13.5, and started seeing a weird dock icon pop up whenever I open a mail app on my iPhone. I want to get rid of this feature. Dock Preferences do not seem to have option to remove it. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn off Handoff.  That's the phone handing off the mail to the Mac.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to just disable the dock icon? I want to keep universal clipboard feature.

Comment: No idea.  The whole idea is so fundamentally broken that I've disabled it completely and haven't missed it.  I use Copied to manage shared clipboard between iOS and OS X.